# Mysql Group by With Condition

Tags: mysql

The below data shows time schedule having elective/ non-elective subjects of a student. My requirement is to select those rows when both elec and nonelec type has same period so in this case select elec type.
 Means for a day's schedule elective (type elec) should be given preference when both having same period. And when type elec does not has period like period 5 then select the non-elective one.

[image]

**My Query**

```
SELECT s.sch_id, s.sch_subtype, sd.sdetail_id, sd.sdetail_period
FROM schedule s
INNER JOIN schedule_detail sd ON s.sch_id = sd.sdetail_schedule
WHERE  '2014-04-30'
BETWEEN sch_datefrom
AND sch_dateto
AND 
(
  (
    sch_section =1
    AND sch_subtype =  'nonelec'
  )
  OR 
  (
    sch_subtype =  'elec'
    AND 272 
    IN 
    (    
      SELECT edetail_stuid
      FROM elective_detail
      WHERE edetail_elective = sch_section
    )
  )
)
AND sch_course =3
AND sch_batch =2
AND sch_termid =2
AND sdetail_day =  'wed'
AND sdetail_period >0
AND CASE WHEN sch_subtype =  'nonelec'
THEN 1 =1
WHEN sch_subtype =  'elec'
THEN sdetail_subject >0
AND sdetail_faculty >0
AND sdetail_room >0
END GROUP BY CASE WHEN sch_subtype =  'elec'
THEN sdetail_period
ELSE 1 
END ORDER BY sdetail_period
```

**Output of above query**

[image]

**Required Output**

[image]

Comment: ....and you tried to code any query from your side?? :)

Comment: yes i used ... group by case when sch_type='elec' then sdetail_period else 1 end ... but not worked

Comment: please post the query also in your question!

Comment: Please post the query that you have tried for us to understand more :)

Comment: check the query i used

Comment: for 2 tables and a single condition, you have pretty huge query...can you show the output you are expecting!!???

Comment: `GROUP BY CASE WHEN sch_subtype = 'elec' THEN sdetail_period ELSE 1 END`????? `else 1`.. how to order with `1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something of this sort :

```
SELECT sch_id,sch_subtype,sdetail_id,sdetail_period 
FROM table 
WHERE condition 
group by sch_subtype
```

It would be better if you can post the query which u tried.

Comment: *It would be better if you can post the query which u tried* - its always better to wait, unless you are eager for rep!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Dont really get whats the problem here:

```
SELECT * FROM schedule s
JOIN schedule_detail sd ON s.sch_id = sd.sdetail_schedule
LEFT JOIN elective_detail ed ON sd.sch_section = ed.edetail_elective
WHERE
(
  sd.sch_section =1
  AND s.sch_subtype =  'nonelec'
)
OR
(
  ed.edetail_stuid = 227
  AND sch_subtype =  'elec'
)
GROUP BY sd.sdetail_period
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69d4e/1

Comment: no this won't work .. becz those students which have opted for elective subject. thats why i have used AND 272 
IN (
SELECT edetail_stuid
FROM elective_detail
WHERE edetail_elective = sch_section
) .. here 272 is student id

Comment: @Sajal difficult to understand what you are trying to do from your query. Maybe add some example to SQL fiddle. Or add some basic table structure with description.
Why it eont work if you add rest of your query? is there some error?

Comment: how can i show you table structure ? is my requirement clear to you.

Comment: I ned to show you 4 tables that are connected but fiddle has limit. Your schema ddl is too large (more than 8000 characters). Please submit a smaller DDL. Anyway thanks for the assistance i will search for some other means.

Comment: @Sajal not really, I think you are trying to do a very simple task, but your query is extremely chaotic. Looks like you have sudent table, schedule table and schedule detail tale. How are student and schedule related? Looks like its through `sch_section`, but dont really know what it means. You should left join students table, gonna edit my answer to show you how

Comment: ok let me explain you whole thing. There is schedule table and schedule_detail having period, subject, faculty and room details. Then there is student table, then elective table which stores info like sub-section name (eg: AB1), course, batch, term, subject, sections(in coma separated). Then finally there is elective_detail which stores students id, those student which opted for AB1. Now what is happening is both sec A and AB1 have different time schedule. I am making a composite report for sec A where attendance of elective subject (AB1) will be given preference.

Comment: OK, 1. coma separated is bad(atomicity)  
2. make a new sql - make a list of tables from which you need data, and how are these databases related.  
3. Make simple select whithout WHERE or GROUP, just joined tables from which you need data, so you see all data(use LEFT/RIGHT JOIN) where needed
4. Add WHERE part, filter only the data you will be needing
5. Add GROUP BY
6. Add ORDER

Comment: yes coma separated is bad(atomicity) but its kind of short cut but i also have detail table to maintain proper normalization. Ok i am trying and lets see. :)